# WPF update textbox while backgroundworker is running

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, backgroundworker, thread-synchronization

I am trying to continuously update my `TextBox` while the `BackgroundWorker` is running.

The code I am using freezes my application:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

int i = 1;

while (worker.IsBusy)
{
   myTextBox.Text = i;
   i++;
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is running on the UI thread so no wonder its freezing the UI. You should move this onto the background worker thread.

Comment: It wont let me update the UI from the background thread

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker ReportProgress

Comment: I guess I should have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you must use [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method to update your UI elements...